# Why is `<style>` declared inside `<head>` of the HTML file?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Why is `<style>` declared inside `<head>` but `<script>` must be put at the bottom of the HTML file?

Here's an example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {background-color: powderblue;}
h1   {color: blue;}
p    {color: red;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1></h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>

<script>
var myHeading = document.querySelector('h1');
myHeading.textContent = 'Hello world!';
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Please let me know about it.

Comment: Are you asking why `<style>` is in the head tag but the `<script>` is not? "_I've seen that must be put at the bottom of the HTML file_" What must be put at the bottom? Where did you find that information?

Comment: are you asking about style or script tag? the reason script tag is at bottom of body is to make sure dom finishes loading before the script runs.

Comment: Is this taken off of w3schools? https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_css.asp

Comment: I am asking about <style> can put bottom of file.

Comment: Some developers put their scripts at the bottom of the <body> as a way to defer loading the script until the all the HTML above it has been parsed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `head` contains general information about the whole document.

The `body` contains the content.

A stylesheet isn't the content, it is information about how the content should look.

---

A script element going at the end of the body is a performance hack.

It is allowed in the body in the first place because it can inject content directly into its current position (with `document.write`), although that isn't considered good practice today.

I would typically put the `<script>` in the `<head>`, but set the `async` attribute and use a `DOMContentLoaded` event listener to make it run when the content has loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You can put  in head also, but it is usually put at the bottom of the body so the styles and page content loads before and then scripts which will result in faster load in time